# How can I store a Date in yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss format without having to change the Data type from Date in Java?

Tags: java, datetime, datetime-format

```
Date x=someobject.getLastRanDate();

System.out.println(x);
```

For the above code, I am getting the output in yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss format. How is this happening or how can we do this ?

Note : `getLastRanDate()` method is getting the date from Database which is storing in the Date Variable.

PS : Please don't answer about SimpleDateFormat.parse(). I explicitly mentioned output variable should be Date object.

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: Use some `SimpleDateFormat` to format the date the way you want. The observed format comes from `Date#toString`

Comment: What is `Sysout`?

Comment: I need to know how we can store the data in  yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss format in a Date variable or how we can pass the date in yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss as a Date data type.

Comment: x is just a date, and what your get printed is one of  several possible formats, you can change it as convenience, follow the @RC advice!

Comment: `Date` is a simple epoch timestamp holder. When you call `toString()` it is parse to be readable. You can define you format like said before.

Comment: I am aware that this isn't an **exact** duplicate. But the point is: as the already existing answers and comments point out, a **Date** object does not carry any formatting. And getting from strings, or to formatted strings for dates is explained in much detail in the dup'ed question.

Comment: Well. In My project, above one is achieved. I mean, if I print a Date data type is printing the output like "2017-03-31 12:00:00" instead of Fri Mar 31 00:00:00 CEST 2017. If there is no formatting for Date object, how it is achieved in the code I have ?

Comment: Maybe you have some custom Date class, it's really easy using an IDE where the `toString` comes from.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, a `Date` represents a point in time. It does not have any `format`. When you execute `System.out.println`, it calls `toString()` method of `Date` class which formats the dates into `String` using default format.

You can use `SimpleDateFormat` class to format the `Date` differntly. However, as far as storing the `date` in database is concerned, you don't need to worry about the format (it's just a representation really), you can define the column type as `Date` or `Datetime` (depending on requirement and database type) and use any framework to persist the `Date` object straight away.

Comment: Answer for my question is :                                                           
 Timestamp ts=new Timestamp(u1.getJoinedDate().getTime());
  Date da=ts;
  System.out.println(da); In this scenario,date variable will print the timestamp formatted output(yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss).

Comment: @M.Nehru You need to let go of the notion that a date-time object such as `java.sql.Date`, `java.util.Date`, or `java.sql.Timestamp` have a format. They do *not* have a format because they are not strings! They each have a `toString` that *generates* a string to represent their value. To generate a String in a particular format, use a formatting class. You would have learned this if you had read the many hundreds of Q&A already posted to Stack Overflow. Please search Stack Overflow before posting.

Comment: @M.Nehru You are using troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

Answer (score 0):

Let's the documention explains itself with [`java.util.Date#toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString())

```
Converts this Date object to a String of the form: 
     dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy

Returns:a string representation of this date.
```

So this `String` is just a representation of the date.

From the same page, you are invited to see [`java.text.DateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) that will explain how to change the format but also give you a subclass [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) explaining every pattern accessible to define your own format.

I can summarize the links more but the javadoc is quite resistant to time (I hope so)